# Struggling with django-filter: NoReverseMatch multiple fields

Tags: django, django-filter

After days I'm relenting to ask this question on SO - my first post!

I'm using django-filter, it was working a few weeks ago but spontaneously broke. I'm fighting complete defeat and 100% appreciate help. I've read the docs dozens of times and think I'm following them to the T... what am I doing wrong?

The error is the dreaded:

```
NoReverseMatch at /test_page/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name."


# location of error @ traceback
return render(request, 'IW_Home/test_page.html', {'filter': f}) …

▼ Local vars Variable   Value
f   
<IW_Home.filters.testFilter object at 0x7f5ac5a80ba8>
params  
1
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/test_page/?connect_attributes__attribute_full__icontains=piano'>
```

Much thanks. Code snippets below.

**filters.py**:

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import CharFilter
from .models import sampleModel

class testFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = IW00010Agencygeneral
        fields = {
            'connect_attributes__attribute_full' : ['icontains'],
        }
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import index,test_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    # Unclear here on whether to use path or url. 
    # Also, when it worked previously I didn't need ^list$
    path('test_page/', test_page, name='test_page'),
    url(r'test_page/^list$', test_page, name='test_page')
]
```

**views**:

```
def test_page(request):
    # Check how many parameters are completed. 
    params = len(parse_qs(request.META['QUERY_STRING']))
    # If no parameters are filled out, return nothing, otherwise, search the table using those search elements
    if params > 0:
        f = testFilter(request.GET, queryset=sampleModel.objects.all().distinct())
    else:
        f = testFilter(request.GET, queryset=sampleModel.objects.all().none())    
    return render(request, 'testAPI/test_page.html', {'filter': f})
```

**test_page.html**:

```
<div id="filterCriteria" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <form method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Search </button>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="main">
      <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Search Criteria</span>
      {% for obj in filter.qs %}
            {{ obj.agency_full }} 
          <br/>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

  </div>
```

**models**:

```
class IW00010Agencygeneral(models.Model):
    agency_id = models.AutoField(db_column='Agency_ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    agency_full = models.TextField(db_column='Agency_Full', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class IW0002GFSPadminAttributes(models.Model):
    runningid = models.AutoField(db_column='RunningID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    agency_id = models.TextField(db_column='FSP_Agency_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    attribute_full = models.IntegerField(db_column='FSP_Hobby_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    agency_connect = models.ForeignKey('IW00010Agencygeneral', to_field='agency_id', db_column='agency_id', related_name='connect_attributes', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you also update the question with more of this code? `return render(request, 'IW_Home/test_page.html', {'filter': f}) …
` the message says the error is occurring here.

Comment: Is this the full template? Have you used any `{% url %}` tags in the template? If so can you add these as well?

Comment: Instead of that error message please show the _proper_ full stack trace of the error (There should be something like "Switch to copy paste view"). Does your `test_page` template have more content, or does it extend some other template? Please show them too. Also show your model `IW00010Agencygeneral` is `agency_full` a method, and it calls `reverse`?

Comment: Hm... I haven't used any {% url %} tags, when it worked a few weeks ago it worked with only the iterable {% for obj in filter.qs %} {% endfor %}. Is this where it's going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your help, 'agency_ful'l is a field in the model

Comment: @EricaDret Please add these to the question and remove anything that not reliant, its very difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - followed instructions!

Comment: @EricaDret unfortunately, the code-snippets in the question are not enough to find the cause of the error, if possible can you share a link to the source code repository?